# R propensity score matching with additional criteria

Tags: r, glm, propensity-score-matching

I have a cohort that looks something like this:

```
id exposure sex age time
 1        0   F  50  300
 2        0   F  55  320
 3        0   F  60  365
 4        0   M  60  335
 5        0   M  65  350
 6        0   M  70  365
 7        1   F  50  310
 8        1   F  50  325
 9        1   M  65  340
10        1   M  70  345
```

I need to create separate matched groups based on `exposure` (dependent variable), matching on covariates `age` and `sex` (independent variables). BUT I must also impose that for each match, `time` is greater for the 'exposed' (`exposure == 1`) observation vs the 'unexposed' (`exposure == 0`) match.

I was planning to use the `MatchIt` command for my propensity score match, but I don't think there's a way to add criteria requiring `time` greater for exposed vs unexposed.

I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in way to do this in `MatchIt`, but `matchit()` allows you to supply any distance matrix you want, with forbidden matches marked with `Inf`. So we we can do is create a distance matrix, then for each exposed unit, set the distance to each control unit to `Inf` if the treated unit's `time` is less than or equal to the control unit's `time`. Here's how this would look:

```
# Estimate a propensity score
df$ps <- glm(exposure ~ sex * age * time, data = df,
          family = binomial)$fitted

# Create distance matrix of ps, with treated units
# on rows and control units on columns
ps_dist <- MatchIt::euclidean_dist(exposure ~ ps, data = df)

# Set to `Inf` any forbidden matches
exposed_times <- df$time[[df$exposure == 1]]
unexposed_times <- df$time[[df$exposure == 0]]
ps_dist[outer(exposed_times, unexposed_times, "<=")] <- Inf

# Supply the distance matrix to `matchit()`
m <- MatchIt::matchit(exposure ~ sex + age + time, data = df,
                      distance = ps_dist)
```